# How to "reset" the find member function of std::string once it reaches end of string

Tags: c++, string, stl, std

Is there a way I can "reset" the function std::string::find to look at the beginning of the string again similar to setting the file pointer in i/o streaming? Thanks.

Comment: No, it does not (although it provides overloads than can work like that *if you cooperate*). If you believe it does, show some code so that we can all be on the same page.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? I thought once it can't find another match, it simply returned string::npos.

Comment: It always looks for the first match. Please read the documentation for any function whose behavior surprises you.

Comment: Do you mean if you start searching from the middle of the string and it doesn't find a match that it starts searching from the beginning of the string?

Comment: Ok evidently I'm not understanding the use of this function.

Comment: @Iowa15: If you know that you don't understand what you're doing, start by [reading the manual](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find), and not by making wild assumptions here and asking others to correct you. If you *don't* know that  you don't understand, add more sanity checks to your general decision making until you do know. If you don't fix this, you may not find programming to be a very enjoyable activity in the long run.

Comment: @Iowa15 You should edit removing incorrect statements

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong. `find` always looks for the first match (or the first match after a specified starting index)

```
std::string str("Hello");

size_t x = str.find("l");
assert(x==2);

x = str.find("l");
assert(x==2);
```

To look for the next match, you have to specify a start position:

```
x = str.find("l",x+1);  //previous x was 2
assert(x==3);

x = str.find("l",x+1); //now x is 3, no subsequent 'l' found
assert(x==std::string::npos);
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually `find` searches the first match after a given index. Here is the default prototype :

```
size_t find (const string& str, size_t pos = 0) const noexcept;
```

By default it starts looking at the index 0 of the string, so :

```
str.find(str2);
```

Is searching the first occurence of `str2` in `str`. If it doesn't find anything it return `std::string::npos`

You can use the function like this :

```
str.find(str2, 4);
```

It will search the first occurence of `str2` in `str` beginning at the index 4. If the string `str` has less than 4 characteres it will return `std::string::npos` again.